# Led blinking with button

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32

I'm programming the F401RE board and i'm trying to switch the led ON/OFF with the press of the button on the board. I'm using a low level approach because it is a university homework and i cannot use high level libraries.

This is what i did, but it is not working, the led stands still...
The code should be right, what am i missing?

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
int main(void){

    int flag=0;
    //PORT REGISTERS
    volatile uint32_t *GPIOA_MODER = (uint32_t*) (0x40020000 + 0x00);
    volatile uint32_t *GPIOA_ODR = (uint32_t*) (0x40020000 + 0x14);
    volatile uint32_t *GPIOC_MODER = (uint32_t*) (0x40020000 + 0x0800 + 0x00);
    volatile uint32_t *GPIOC_IDR = (uint32_t*) (0x40020000 + 0x0800 + 0x10);

    //CLOCK REGISTERS
    volatile uint32_t *RCC_AHB1ENR = (uint32_t*) (0x40023800 + 0x30);

    *RCC_AHB1ENR |= 0x05U;

    *GPIOA_MODER = *GPIOA_MODER | 0x400;

    *GPIOC_MODER = *GPIOC_MODER | 0x0C000000;

    *GPIOA_ODR = *GPIOA_ODR | 0x20;

    // Application code (Infinite loop)
    while (1){

        if((((*GPIOC_IDR>>13) & 0x01) == 0x01)){
            flag=1;
        }else if((((*GPIOC_IDR>>13) & 0x01) == 0x00)  && flag==1){
            *GPIOA_ODR = *GPIOA_ODR ^ 0x20;
            flag=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of troubleshooting have you done already? Can you toggle the light on/off with a software delay loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Warning: I'm **not** an expert with this specific MCU. Be careful.*

All MCU register information pulled from [this](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/5d/b1/ef/b2/a1/66/40/80/DM00096844.pdf/files/DM00096844.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00096844.pdf) reference manual.

---

Anyways, now that I've finished making my disclaimers, let's dive in.

```
//Lines 16-20
...
*GPIOA_MODER = *GPIOA_MODER | 0x400;

*GPIOC_MODER = *GPIOC_MODER | 0x0C000000;

*GPIOA_ODR = *GPIOA_ODR | 0x20;
...
```

This is, I believe, the segment of code that contains the error. You set `GPIOA_MODER5` to use general purpose output mode, and `GPIOC_MODER13` to use analog mode. Once again, not an expert here, but I believe this should be set to use input mode. Either don't do anything (as port C's reset value is `0x00000000`) or explicitly reset that part of the register with `*GPIOC_MODER = *GPIOC_MODER & ~(0x0C000000);`.

---

In the course of debugging this, I reformatted your code to fit my university's coding standards as well as my personal preferences. Here it is.

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"

//Magic numbers are BAD. Use macros instead.
#define GPIOA_MEMOFFSET 0x40020000
#define GPIOC_MEMOFFSET 0x40020800
#define CLOCK_MEMOFFSET 0x40023800

//more macros. These are bit offsets for various registers.
#define GPIOC_MODER13 26
#define GPIOA_MODER5 10
#define GPIOC_IDR13 13
#define GPIOA_ODR5 5
#define RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN 0
#define RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN 1

int main(void)
{
    //Different compilers have different lengths for ints.
    //uint8_t is always 8 bits long.

    uint8_t flag=0;

    //This area has been width formatted to be easier to read. 
    //The compiler doesn't care about whitespace. See the macros at work?

    //PORT REGISTERS
    volatile uint32_t *GPIOA_MODER = (uint32_t*) (GPIOA_MEMOFFSET + 0x00);
    volatile uint32_t *GPIOA_ODR   = (uint32_t*) (GPIOA_MEMOFFSET + 0x14);
    volatile uint32_t *GPIOC_MODER = (uint32_t*) (GPIOC_MEMOFFSET + 0x00);
    volatile uint32_t *GPIOC_IDR   = (uint32_t*) (GPIOC_MEMOFFSET + 0x10);
    //CLOCK REGISTERS
    volatile uint32_t *RCC_AHB1ENR = (uint32_t*) (CLOCK_MEMOFFSET + 0x30);

    //No, it's not as concise as your version. But since all of this is constant,
    //any GOOD compiler will literally turn all that into a 5. It makes debugging
    //for other programmers easier to see what's actually going on. 
    *RCC_AHB1ENR |= (1 << RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN) | (1<<RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN); 

    //I turned every assignment operator into its equivalent boolean assignment.
    *GPIOA_MODER |= (0b01 << GPIOA_MODER5);
    *GPIOA_MODER &= ~(0b10 << GPIOA_MODER5);

    *GPIOC_MODER &= ~(0b11 << GPIOC_MODER13);

    *GPIOA_ODR = *GPIOA_ODR | (1 << GPIOA_ODR5);

    // Application code (Infinite loop)
    while (1)
    {
        //Lots of work here. C standard defines false as 0 and true as !false
        //so you're able to turn 'if (xx!=0)' into just 'if (xx)'
        //...usually. The rules get iffy when you do weird things. 
        if (*GPIOC_IDR & (1<<GPIOC_IDR13)) //AND masking IDR13.
        {
            flag=1;
        }
        else if(!(*GPIOC_IDR & (1<<GPIOC_IDR13)) && flag) //AND masking IDR13 again, but also boolean inverting the result. 
        {
            *GPIOA_ODR ^= (1<<GPIOA_ODR5);
            flag=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i messed up with GPIOC_MODER. Thanks also for the reformatting!

Comment: I'm surprised you don't already have a .h file full of those defines...

Comment: **There should be a delay after enabling the GPIO bits in `RCC_AHB1ENR`**, either a `__DSB()` instruction or reading back the register. See *Delay after an RCC  peripheral clock enabling* in the product errata document.

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending to use port pin PC13 for the button input?  ORing GPIOC_MODER with 0x0C000000 sets PC13 for Analog mode.  I think you want Input mode instead of Analog mode.  Input mode is the default for PC13.  So try just commenting out the following line.

```
//    *GPIOC_MODER = *GPIOC_MODER | 0x0C000000;
```